# ansible - Nothing happens when executing InstallHalyard.sh script via ansible-playbook

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

I'm trying to make a playbook to install halyard on a remote host using ansible-playbook. One of the tasks is to execute the "InstallHalyard.sh" wrapper scripts to the actual installer (reference: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/).

No error / failure present, but also nothing has changed, as if the InstallHalyard.sh script is not executed. Though, it's fine if I do it by typing manual command. The other similar task works perfectly.

You can see the InstallHalyard.sh script implementation: [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spinnaker/halyard/master/install/stable/InstallHalyard.sh)

**Any idea about what is happening?**

Here is the task in my playbook:

```
name: Run InstallHalyard.sh
  become: yes
  become_user: sudo
  shell: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.spinnaker/InstallHalyard.sh"
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much :)

**EDIT:**

Already tried using script, command, and shell module.

FYI, the InstallHalyard.sh script will call itself by passing an env variable and needs to do curl -O

I'm suspecting the "export" operation inside the script doesn't work as Ansible has a different  understandings for environment vars. (For example, ansible will not recognize "$HOME" instead it uses "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}".)

**EDIT:**

I found the script does an operation that makes a fork, does ansible handle this kind of operation?

Tested on localhost, got the same result.

**SOLUTION**

It is because of the different interpretation of environment vars of ansible. If I executed the script manually, the wrapper sets the environment variable and pass it to the next script calls, which ansible not able to do. So what I do is setting the environment var manually with ansible module before executing the script (just adding 2 lines)

Here is my revised task:

```
name: Run InstallHalyard.sh
  become: yes
  become_user: sudo
  environment:
    HAL_USER: "{{ ansible_env.USER }}"
  shell: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.spinnaker/InstallHalyard.sh"
```

Comment: You should check the base path directory, you might replace the relative path with the absolute path for the executables into InstallHalyard.sh script. And watch out the sudo mean the user is root user. Its environment variable is based on root.

Comment: Can you try using: command: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.spinnaker/InstallHalyard.sh"

Comment: @Daein the {{ ansible_env.HOME }} gives the current user $HOME env variable which is /home/user, means it implies absolute path, I also tried by manually typed the absolute path, still not working. Thanks for answering

Comment: @abhishekphukan already tried it, nothing happened. Thank you for answering

Comment: FYI, the InstallHalyard.sh script will call the itself by passing an env variable and needs to do curl -O

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a help site for installing programs found on GitHub.

Comment: @techraf it's actually not the script problem but the ansible ad-hoc type of error which occurs now, and I like to know the root cause, basically.

Comment: @techraf I suppose it should cover the purpose, because all it need is to "execute a script" which is why I tried "shell", "command", and "script" module.

However, the script has some operation that do fork, do ansible playbook handle such operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is really how do I debug the output of a failing command. I'm guessing the command is failing with a useful error message but that message is not being displayed anywhere.

Here is an example to help debug this failing script:

```
-name: Run InstallHalyard.sh
   become: yes
   become_user: sudo
   shell: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.spinnaker/InstallHalyard.sh"
   register: output

- debug: msg="{{ output.stdout }}"

- debug: msg="{{ output.stderr }}"
```

Try that is see what error message it was giving you.

Comment: Yes. I actually got the error by viewing the task verbose (-v) when invoking ansible-playbook. Thanks for the answer